# Como faço para permitir apenas numeros e um caractere especial no javascript?

Tags: javascript, validação

Estou com um problema de validação no client-side no caso estou querendo validar o campo CEP, preciso que ele apenas aceite os 9 números do CEP da pessoa e o  traço **`-`** do CEP, quem poder ajudar agradeço desde já.

Esta é uma parte do codigo:

```
if(isNaN(cep) || tc.length<10){
   alert('digite seu cep corretamente');
   document.form.cep.style.background='red';
   return false;
}
```

Este código esta entrando em conflito com minha necessidade pois coloquei pra aceitar apenas numero com o `isNaN` e não sei como fazer para aceitar números e apenas um caractere especial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma alternativa seria utilizar um plugin de máscara com jQuery:

```js
$('#txtCep').mask('99999-999');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cloud.github.com/downloads/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.js"></script>

<form>
  CEP: <input type="text" id="txtCep" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Seu código ficaria assim com uma verificação por `regex`:

```
if (!/^[0-9]{5}\-[0-9]{3}$/.test(cep)){
   alert('digite seu cep corretamente');
   document.form.cep.style.background='red';
   return false;
}
```

**EDIT 1**

Complementando com alguma explicação seguindo o exemplo do @Sergio♦

Na `regex` acima o `^` significa o começo da cadeia de caracteres, ou seja, não será aceito nada diferente do que se segue. O `[0-9]` quer dizer que são aceitos dígitos de `0` a `9`. O `{X}` diz a quantidade de vezes que o termo anterior irá aparecer consecutivamente. O `\-` significa exatamente o caractere `-`. O `$` exige que seja o final da cadeia de caracteres, impedindo assim que haja mais alguma coisa após o que foi testado.
A sequência `[0-9]` também pode ser alterada para `\d`, e o resultado seria o seguinte:

```
/^\d{5}\-\d{3}$/
```

Comment: Acho que a regex poderia ser melhorada para **/^[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}$/** já que a que você postou permite CEPs assim "h12345-678" e assim "12345-7890"

Comment: É verdade, vou editar com a sua sugestão

Comment: Em regex `-` é um caracter especial e deve ser escapado.

Comment: Vou melhorar isso também então

Answer (score 2):

Sugiro teres uma função que limpa os espaços em branco e depois verifica a estrutura `5 digitos > traço > 3 digitos`. Poderia ser assim:

```js
function isCEP(str) {
    return !!str.split(' ').join('').match(/^\d{5}\-\d{3}$/);
}

['12345-678', '123 45 - 678 ', '12345678', '1234-5678'].forEach(function(cep) {
    console.log(isCEP(cep));
});
```

Na regex uso `\d` que quer dizer numero/digito, `\-` que quer dizer traço, e `{x}` que quer dizer que espera x vezes o tipo de caracter antes do `{}` na regex.